# Searching for first set bit in a huge bitmap

Tags: c

Interview question:

In a parking slot which can hold million cars, you need to find a *free* parking slot. There is no condition on where the slot could be, i.e., the parking lot can have multiple entrances and finding a slot near the entrance, etc., does not matter. The question was what kind of data structure should be used and what would be complexity of various operations.

I suggested using a bit array of million bits, with 0/1 for taken/free slot, so for finding free spot the question translated to finding first set bit. Do not assume anything about how many cars are there, etc., i.e., the bit array could be sparse or dense.

What is the fastest way to find a set bit in a huge bitmap? I did suggest binary search + efficient ffs() per word as the scheme.

Comment: If we can't assume anything about the contents of the array, then a binary search will not help here; you'll have to use a linear search.

Comment: In c, you can go through the slots in 64-bit groups (using uint64_t), and check for the first nonzero value.

Comment: I'd binary search on a Fenwick Tree (Binary Indexed Tree, BIT). Update operation takes O(log n). Searching for first set bit is O((log n) ^ 2)

Comment: @H2CO3 This would be linear scan, right? It is just that you are checking in chunks of 64 bits ( or native word size to be more specific ) instead of bit by bit.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by: "There is condition on where the slot could be i.e. the parking slot can have multiple entrances and finding a slot near entrace etc does not matter".

Comment: related: [bitscan](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Bitscan applies only in part, because the cost of finding the set bit in a nonzero word will very likely be outweighted by the costs of finding a nonzero word in the first place.

Comment: @MvG: yes. It should be obvious. Thanks for stating it explicitly. I've stumbled upon the link while thinking about a solution that uses a very shallow tree with 32/64 branching factor. The solution probably is not worth it but the link is interesting I thought I would share.

Answer (score 9):

A million 32-bit integers require about 4MB of memory. So I'd say you keep a list of free slots. Whenever a car enters, you take an item off the list and assign that. Whenever a car leaves, you put the freed slot number into the list.

As you'd only ever be manipulating the end of the list (so this is in fact used as a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) or [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29) structure), this gives you optimal O(1) performance both for finding a free slot and for returning a slot to free state. If you do this on a low level with a raw chunk of memory, you'll need a pointer indicating the current end of the list. Finding a slot decrements that pointer and returns its value. Returning a slot assigns to the pointer and increments it afterwards.

If you decide to add additional requirements later on, you could do some manipulation of your data, e.g. turn it into a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). With a big map of 0/1 bits, such extensions wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Heh, I love answers like this. I think most people - myself included - tend to forget quite how obscenely powerful modern computers are. Keeping track of a few million ints? Peh, my phone could do that without even registering the load!

Comment: @LexiR, even on a machine 15 years old, this approach would work well. Most of the list might get swapped to disk, but the single active end would be readily available in physical memory. You only need a backing store larger than a floppy disk, and an operating system which is able to swap out memory. A severely memory-constrained microcontroller might be a different thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way:

Store the index of the last free slot in a variable and then looking for the next one don't scan the bitmap from the beginning, but from this value.

If you need to free some slot, assign it to the last index.

`std::vector<bool>` can be your bit array, so you will not need to deal with bits yourself (bool's are packed into ints internally).

You can introduce a `mip-mapped` structure:

```
``std::vector<bool>`` Bitmap;
``std::vector<bool>`` Bitmap2; // half-sized
``std::vector<bool>`` Bitmap4; // 1/4
``std::vector<bool>`` Bitmap8; // 1/8
// etc
```

The `free` values in the upper-level arrays correspond to the situation where the lower level array have any free slots. You can use binary search to traverse this structure.

Comment: The mip-mapping will be quite expensive unless you keep track of fill rates or similar. Otherwise you'd have to check whether to update the other levels during each pass.

Comment: Mip-mapping will add ~33% memory overhead and will allow search in linear time. So its a tradeoff.